# Importing node_revisions records from version 5 to version 6

Tags: nodes, 6, migrations

Probably a dumb question, but could I simply export an SQL file from the database of a Drupal 5 site and import it into a Drupal 6 database in the same table provided I used the same CCK fields for both? I've tried to migrate content in so many different ways and pretty much everything has failed so far... importing csv through the feeds module was my greatest hope and was made to look so easy but I keep getting an HTTP error.

Also is node_revisions the table that contains all of the stories? I tried exporting nodes, but it didn't seem to contain the body field.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying some convoluted way of exporting and then re-importing the data and maintaining all meta-data - have you tried simply upgrading the site to Drupal 6?

This has been heavily documented on [drupal.org](http://drupal.org/documentation/upgrade/5/6)

When you do a major drupal upgrade, so long as there is a drupal 6 module for your functionality, there will be update hooks that alter the database to convert it to the new schema.

This includes CCK, revisions etc

Comment: Yes I have tried... failed miserably :( the drupal 5 site I am dealing with is very poorly coded, and that may have to do with the many hurdles I'm running into... I will try again if all else fails.

Comment: The trick is to read the whole upgrade guide, make sure ALL contrib is disabled before updating core, and make sure you are running the latest version of 5.x first.

Comment: OK I guess I have no other choice than to try again... but then what do I do to recover the stories once I've upgraded (if I manage to upgrade)? Thanks!

Comment: If you follow the upgrade path, all content will come with you too.

Comment: But the idea here is to transfer the nodes to a different site. Not to keep them in the same site after upgrading...

Comment: @Jane, the different site is empty or have content ?

Comment: It's empty, just a theme, content types and views and a couple of other similar things.